# Integration by parts, Reduction

Tags: integration

[image]

I was able to complete part (a) easily by using integration by parts. I ended up getting:

$$I(n) = -\frac{1}{n} \cos x\cdot \sin^{n-1}x + \frac{n-1}{n}· I(n-2)$$

For question (b), When I integrated $1/\sin^4x$ and subbed in $n = -4$, I get the following equation:

$$\frac{1}{4}·\cos x·\sin^{-5}x + \frac{5}{4} \int sin^{-6}x dx$$

My question is, how do I integrate $\sin^{-6}x$ because it's not the same as integrating $\sin^{6}x$, which will actually get you somewhere. It feels like I'm going in a loop when integrating $\sin^{-6}x$.
I might have went wrong somewhere, help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe you should integrate $\sin^{-2}x$.

Comment: Start with $n=-2$

Comment: ohh okay, i think i get it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting $n=-2,$ in  $$I_n=-\frac1n\cos x\sin^{n-1}x+\frac{n-1}nI_{n-2}$$

we get   $$I_{-2}=-\frac1{(-2)}\cos x\sin^{-2-1}x+\frac{(-2-1)}{(-2)}I_{-2-2}$$

$$\implies  \frac32I_{-4}=I_{-2}-\frac{\cos x}{2\sin^3x}$$

Now, $$I_{-2}=\int\sin^{-2}xdx=\int \csc^2xdx=-\cot x+C$$

Can you finish it from here?

Comment: how do i ask a new question?

Comment: @GeorgeRandall, press "ASK QUESTION" at the top right

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start,

$$ I_n = \int \sin^{n-2}(x) \sin^2(x) dx = \int \sin^{n-2}(x) (1-\cos^2(x)) dx $$

$$ = \int \sin^{n-2}(x)dx - \int \sin^{n-2}(x)\cos(x)\cos(x)dx \dots. $$

Can you finish it? Use integration by parts to evaluate the last integral.

Comment: George "was able to complete part (a) easily "

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: I just paid attention. We can just leave it for those who may not know how to find part (a). Thanks for the comment.